# How to create an array of ints when size of array and size of ints are not constant?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to create an array of integers with the aim of using them one by one later in the program. Integers are inputted by the user, so the size of the array and the size of each integer aren't constant. All I can say that due to specification of the program the array would not exceed, let's say, **100 elements** and an integer would always be **between 0 and 99**. How can I do this? I am new to C and this is really baffling to me, as this is very easy to do in Python, and I've spent quite some time already trying to figure out how to make this work (I understand that all those complications with arrays arise from the fact that C is an old language).

Comment: Google for "dynamic arrays in c".

Comment: And read documentation for the `realloc()` function.

Comment: complications with dynamic arrays are not caused from C being an old language, they are caused by C being a very efficient language!

Comment: `malloc` and `realloc` is the way to go. And it's not because C is an old language. Blasphemer!

Comment: You can declare an array `int numbers[100];` which will store up to 100 numbers of the range you want. Also declare a variable for example, `int count=0;` so you know how many  elements of the array you have used. Once you have that working, you can explore the more complex method of memory allocation.

Comment: Restricting the range of the integers would best be accomplished by validating the input, ie, `if ( input < 0 || input > 99 ) { /*bug the user to reenter*/}`

Comment: Given a modest upper bound on the number of elements required (and 100 is quite modest), @WeatherVane's suggestion to declare an ordinary array with static size sufficient for that maximum number of members is very reasonable.  It is by far the easiest approach available, enough so that for one-offs it may be sensible to use it even for much (much) larger upper bounds.

Comment: If the program is only going to have this one array and you make sure not to let the user input more than 100 (by keeping a counter), there is little reason not to declare it as `int nums[100];` up front. 400 bytes of memory is nothing to worry about and it makes it easier for the programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't confuse an integer *value* with the size of the type used to represent it.  The values `0` and `99` will take up exactly the same amount of space in whatever integral type you use.

As for the array itself, you have several options available.

You can pick a meximum number of elements that your user won't be allowed to exceed:

```
#define MAX_ALLOWED 100

int main( void )
{
  int values[MAX_ALLOWED];  // declare array with max-allowed values
  size_t howMany;

  // get howMany from user, make sure it doesn't exceed MAX_ALLOWED
  ...
}
```

If you are using a C99 or C2011 compiler that supports variable-length arrays, you could get the array length from the user and use that value in the array
declaration:

```
int main( void )
{
  size_t howMany;

  // get howMany from user

  int values[howMany];  // declare array with user-specified number of values
  ...
}
```

If you don't want to use VLAs (and there are some good reasons why you don't), you can use dynamic memory management routines:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
  size_t howMany;

  // get howMany from user

  int *values = malloc( howMany * sizeof *values );  // dynamically allocate
                                                     // space to store user-
                                                     // specified number of
                                                     // values.
  if ( !values )
  {
    // memory allocation failed, panic
    exit( 0 );
  }
  ...
  free( values ); // release the memory when you're done.
}
```

Note that in the last case, `values` is not declared as an array of `int`, but a pointer to `int`; it will store the address of the memory that was dynamically allocated.  You can still use the `[]` operator to index into that space like a regular array, but in many other respects it will not be treated the same as an array.

Regardless of how you create the array, assigning elements is the same:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < howMany; i++ )
{
  values[i] = value_for_this_element();
}
```